# Connect or disconnect iPhone to internet programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, tcp, network-programming

Is it possible to connect or disconnect an iPhone to internet connection (via Wi-Fi or 3G) programmatically if I know the IP address of the iPhone.

I have developed a small app which will give all devices connected to my router.
Suppose 3 devices are connected to my router viz . Device A, B & C.

At some point I want to disconnect the device B forcefully may be because it is using more of my internet bandwidth. So is it possible to do or not.
If yes... what should be my approach ?.

I just need to achieve connect or disconnect functionality.

Thanks,

Comment: sounds interesting...

Comment: It seems like the router would have to do that as you can't remotely control an iPhone like that and you can't monitor an iPhones total bandwidth from within an app.